# Generate a 10 digit number for n times

Tags: php

```
<?php
$rand = "06".mt_rand(0,9)."".mt_rand(0,9)."".mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9);

print_r($rand); ?>
```

i want to use this code to generate 100 random numbers, then save the results in a txt file. I just don't know how to keep the code working until it reaches 100 digit numbers

Desired output

```
 0643895810
 0680345345
 0668104431
... 100 times
```

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop ? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: i don't know how to do that, i'm new to php

Comment: It doesn't really get any more simple. A for loop is one of the first things you need to learn if you are going to write code. You will have to learn at some point, why not now.

Comment: @Timo A for loop is one of the most basic control structures in all of programming, not just PHP.    SO isn't a place for you if you haven't at least tried the basics.

Comment: A loop is a nice way to do a punition when you have to display 10 000 lines of `"I will be a lazy developper"`. 2 lines of code and you're done. I strongly suggest you to follow a **complete** tutorial about php (for beginner)

Comment: https://phpapprentice.com/loops.html

Comment: guys guys, i tried a lot of stuff yesterday it just doesn't work the way i want it, i'm just saying an example would help me understand and learn at the same time

Comment: Don't want to sound rude, but have you checked the PHP manual page Matthew posted? There are examples on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php). A loop allows you to do something so many times you want.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
}
```

`$i++` is called *Post-increment* it just sets `$i` + 1. So it's like `$i = $i + 1`.

Now put your random number string in the for loop.

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo "06".mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9)."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Don't forget to add a `<br>` at the end. It's a line break. If you want to use it in a textfile you have to use `\n`.

Comment: my code works good i just want multiple prints like
print_r($rand); for 100 times and each code in a line

Comment: @Timo Just put  print_r($rand); in the for loop.

Comment: @Jakob it's like repeating print_r 100 times so each generated code will be printed to make a list of 100 digits like 064295745 / 0675102039 / .... etc

Comment: @Jakob a list of 100 numbers printed each one in a line

Comment: @Jakob i updated the post so you can see the output i want

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi take a look up at the desired output, this is not what i need